# Stop the whole traffic if VPN gets disconnected - Disable network (Shell script)

Tags: shell, connection, vpn

Hello stackoverflow members, 
I'm in need of a Shell Script which checks if the VPN Connection gets changed or not. If it got changed (vpn disconnected) the network will be disabled and no data can go out. Therefore will be no IP leak. I have checked already many sites, and I have found a interesting python script. Here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#
# licensed under GNU General Public License version 2
#

import sys
import traceback

import gobject

import dbus
import dbus.decorators
import dbus.mainloop.glib

import os

def catchall_signal_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    print ("Caught signal: "+ kwargs['member'])
    if args[0] >= 6: #vpn disconnect (6) or failure (7)
        print ("Killing internet connection...")
    #set eth0 to your network adapter
        os.system('ifconfig eth0 down')
    #if you are using python 3 no raw_input() exists so use input()
    raw_input("Press Enter to enable your network adapter...")
    #set eth0 to your network adapter
    os.system('ifconfig eth0 up')
     print ("Your network adapter has been enabled.")   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    print ("Monitoring your VPN connection...")
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()

    #lets make a catchall
    bus.add_signal_receiver(catchall_signal_handler, signal_name='VpnStateChanged', interface_keyword='dbus_interface', member_keyword='member')

    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

The problem is, that it seemed to work only for 1 time. It's really weird.
So, I ask you as an expert where the issue could be. If someone would also have another script which is more optimized I would appreciate so much!

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards,

Comment: When you say it only worked once, do you mean once per session or once and never again? What is the state of the adapter after this script runs (does it come back up when you press enter)?

Comment: Hello, it worked once and never again. I have tried to reboot and do it again, but it didn't work. When I press enter after I runed it, it prints that the adapter has been enabled...
I have tried to enable the adapter manually with: 'sudo ifconfig eth0 up' and then I have tried the script again, but if I disconnect the VPN, the script says that it has stopped the traffic, but the net is still working.. It's really weird..